# ¿Cómo implementar HTML dinamica con base de datos usando mysqli, php y css?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, css3, mysqli

Estuve practicando sobre como mostrar, añadir y eliminar con html dinamicamente, aunque no he comprendido del todo, he pasado varios años sin programar por motivos personales, he ahí los códigos correspondientes:

**facturacion.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!--Parte correspondiente a Jquery -->

<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css”>
<script src=”https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js”></script>
<script src=”https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js”></script>

<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="orden.css"/>
<img src="corgi.jpeg" align="left" alt="Logo compania" width="100" height="100">
<title>Facturacion</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="facturacion.php" method="post">
 <table width="200" border="1" aligm="center">
 <br><tr><td>Num_Fact</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="num_fact" name="num_fact" placeholders="Escriba numero factura"/></br></td></tr>
 <br><tr><td>RUT</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="rut" name="rut" placeholders="Escriba Rut"/></br></td></tr>
 <br><tr><td>Cliente</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="cliente" name="cliente" placeholders="Escriba cliente"/></br></td></tr>
 <br><tr><td>Num_fact</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="num_fact" name="num_fact" placeholders="Escriba num_fact"/></br></td></tr>
 <br><tr><td>Direccion</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="Direccion" name="Direccion" placeholders="Escriba Direccion"/></br></td></tr>
 </table> 
<table id="factura">
 <tr>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Nombre Producto</th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th>Descripcion</th>
  <th>Precio Venta</th>
  <th>Total</th>
 </tr>
</table>
<table> 
 <tr><td>Codigo
 <input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo" placeholders="Insertar codigo"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Nombre Producto
 <input type="text" id="nombre_producto" name="nombre_producto" placeholders="Inserta nombre_producto"/></tr></td>
 <tr><td>Cantidad
 <input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" placeholders="Inserta cantidad"/>
 </tr></td>
 <tr><td>Descripcion
 <input type="text" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" placeholders="Inserta descripcion"/>
 </tr></td>
 <tr><td>Precio venta
 <input type="text" id="precio_venta" name="precio_venta" placeholders="Inserta precio_venta"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td>Total
 <input type="text" id="total" name="total" placeholders="Inserta total"/></td></tr>
</table> 

<input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
<input type="reset" value="Resetear"/>
<input type="button" value="Cancelar"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**facturacion.php**

```html
<?php

$conn;
require ('conexion.php');

conn();

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$nombre_producto = $_POST['nombre_producto'];
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$precio_venta = $_POST['precio_venta'];
$total = $_POST['total'];

$insertar = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO facturacion VALUES ('".$codigo."', '".$nombre_producto."', '".$cantidad."', '".$descripcion."', '".$precio_venta."', '".$total."')");

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $insertar);

if (!$resultado){
 echo '<script>alert("facturacion registrada")</script>';
} else {
 echo '<script>alert("Error, facturacion no registrada")</script>';
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

**orden.css**

```css
body {
 color:  black;
 text-align:  center;
 background-color: blue;
}

#factura {
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#factura td,  #factura th {
 border:  1px solid #ddd;
 padding:  8px;
}

#factura tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color:  #f2f2f2;
}

#factura th {
 padding-top: 12px;
 padding-bottom: 12px;
 text-align:  left;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;

}
```

[image: Facturacion phpmyadmin]

He estado investigando por todos los medios como implementarlo correctamente la tabla correspondiente con html dinámico y no hubo ninguna respuesta al respecto para añadir, eliminar y mostrar a través del base de datos.

Sé que **facturacion.html** es un desorden, por esto he tratado de todos los medios para implementar html dinámico.

Espero sus comentarios y algunas ayudas técnicas para comprender html dinámico con php, mysqli y css.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de ver la parte visual, hay que tener claro el concepto de mostrar, insertar y actualizar valores en la base de datos. Solo has presentado el código para insertar un registro, pero no para mostrar en pantalla, ni para actualizar.
En el siguiente ejemplo, propongo en una sola página las 3 funciones básicas.

Obviamente se que en un desarrollo más avanzado esto no se hace de la manera que lo muestro, pero sirve de fines didácticos y que entiendas los conceptos.

Como no tenía una base de datos MySQL para hacer las pruebas, este código lo hice para `SQLite`. Si lo quieres probar, asegúrate que en tu `php.ini` esté habilitada la extensión **sqlite3** y copia y pega el código en un archivo que se tiene que llamar ***paginatest.php*** ya que hay llamados explícitos hacia ese nombre de archivo.

Adicional, para reducir la complejidad, solo creé una tabla con 4 registros, num_fact, rut, cliente, direccion y también eliminé todos los formatos de tabla y css.
Ya es cuestión tuya que lo vayas adaptando a tus requerimientos y agregándole los formatos, css, js, etc.

> paginatest.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pregunta de StackOverflow</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
function crear_base_datos() {
    $conexion = new SQLite3('TestDB.db3');  
    $create_table = "CREATE TABLE Factura (
        id         INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        num_fact   VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
        rut        VARCHAR (12) NOT NULL,
        cliente VARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
        direccion  VARCHAR (45) 
    )";
    $conexion->exec($create_table);
}

function insertar_registro() {
    $num_fact = $_POST['num_fact'];
    $rut = $_POST['rut'];
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO Factura (num_fact, rut, cliente, direccion) 
    VALUES ('$num_fact', '$rut', '$cliente', '$direccion')";
    $conexion = new SQLite3('TestDB.db3');
    if($conexion->query($query)) {
        echo '<p>Registro insertado correctamente</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Ocurrio un problema insertando el registro</p>';
    }
}

function modificar_registro() {
    $fact_id = $_POST['fid'];
    $num_fact = $_POST['num_fact'];
    $rut = $_POST['rut'];
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $query = "UPDATE Factura 
    SET num_fact='$num_fact', rut='$rut', cliente='$cliente', direccion='$direccion' 
    WHERE id=$fact_id";
    $conexion = new SQLite3('TestDB.db3');
    if($conexion->query($query)) {
        echo '<p>Registro modificado correctamente</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Ocurrio un problema modificando el registro</p>';
    }
}

function formulario_editar_reg() {
    $fact_id = $_GET['fid'];
    $query = "SELECT num_fact, rut, cliente, direccion FROM Factura WHERE id=$fact_id";
    $conexion = new SQLite3('TestDB.db3');
    $result = $conexion->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetchArray();
    ?>
    <h4>Editar Registro</h4>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Editar" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="<?php echo $fact_id;?>" />
        Num_Fact <input type="text" name="num_fact" value="<?php echo $row['num_fact'];?>"/></br>
        Rut <input type="text" name="rut" value="<?php echo $row['rut'];?>"/></br>
        Cliente<input type="text" name="cliente" value="<?php echo $row['cliente'];?>"/></br>
        Direccion <input type="text" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $row['direccion'];?>"/></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Modificar"/></br>
    </form>
    <?php
}

function formulario_nuevo_reg() {
    ?>
    <h4>Insertar nuevo registro</h4>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="Nuevo" />
        Num_Fact <input type="text" name="num_fact" /></br>
        Rut <input type="text" name="rut" /></br>
        Cliente<input type="text" name="cliente" /></br>
        Direccion <input type="text" name="direccion" /></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Insertar"/></br>
    </form>
    <?php
}

function mostrar_registros() {
    echo '<h4>Registros Actuales</h4>';
    $conexion = new SQLite3('TestDB.db3');
    $query = "SELECT id, num_fact, rut, cliente, direccion FROM Factura";
    $results = $conexion->query($query);
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
        echo $row['num_fact'] . ' - ';
        echo $row['rut'] . ' - ';
        echo $row['cliente'] . ' - ';
        echo $row['direccion'] . ' - ';
        echo '<a href="paginatest.php?fid='.$row['id'].'">Editar</a><br />';
    }
}

// ############ EJECUCION INICIA AQUI ###############
if (!file_exists('TestDB.db3')) {
    // Si la base de datos no existe, crearla
    crear_base_datos();
}

if(isset($_POST['action']) and ($_POST['action'] == 'Nuevo')) {
    insertar_registro();
    echo '<p><a href="paginatest.php">Regresar</a></p>';
} elseif(isset($_POST['action']) and ($_POST['action'] == 'Editar')) {
    modificar_registro();
    echo '<p><a href="paginatest.php">Regresar</a></p>';
} elseif(isset($_GET['fid'])) {
    formulario_editar_reg();
    echo '<p><a href="paginatest.php">Regresar</a></p>';
} else {
    mostrar_registros();
    formulario_nuevo_reg();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder esto, creo que comprendí bien en el uso de las cinco funciones para los botones.

Answer (score 0):

Sin mirar al detalle, el planteamiento parece correcto.

En las consultas, los números enteros van sin comillas. Por ejemplo `$cantidad`. Recuerdo tener errores de ese tipo, y las comillas dobles creo que sobran excepto la primera y la última.

`mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO facturacion VALUES ('.$codigo.', '.$nombre_producto.',$cantidad, '.$descripcion.', '.$precio_venta.', '.$total.')")`